# Ren'py Uncaught Exception Before Game Starts For Unknown Reason

Tags: python, renpy

I was happily programming along in Ren'py 6.99.14.3, and I launched the game and I got an error.  I tried going back to the last time the game worked in my script and I still had the error.  I tried investigating it for a while, but I hadn't the slightest idea (probably as a beginner).

Here is the first part of the 'traceback.txt' (Not the Full Traceback part)

```
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

After initialization, but before game start.
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 714, in prepare_screen
    screen preferences():
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 714, in prepare
    screen preferences():
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 718, in prepare
    use game_menu(_("Preferences"), scroll="viewport"):
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 718, in prepare
    use game_menu(_("Preferences"), scroll="viewport"):
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 720, in prepare
    vbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 720, in prepare
    vbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 722, in prepare
    hbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 722, in prepare
    hbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 725, in prepare
    if renpy.variant("pc"):
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 725, in prepare
    if renpy.variant("pc"):
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 727, in prepare
    vbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 727, in prepare
    vbox:
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 730, in prepare
    textbutton _("Window") action Preference("display", "window")
  File "game/screens.rpy", line 730, in prepare
    textbutton _("Window") action Preference("display", "window")
  File "renpy/common/00preferences.rpy", line 454, in Preference
    rv = get()
  File "renpy/common/00preferences.rpy", line 211, in get
    return __DisplayAction(1.0)
  File "renpy/common/00preferences.rpy", line 27, in __init__
    self.width = int(factor * config.screen_width)
Exception: Character expects its what argument to be a string, got 1280.0.
```

I will provide more information if you want, and if I can

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"Exception: Character expects its what argument to be a string, got 1280.0."
```

Did you define one of your characters as "int", like this?

```
define int = Character ('Name', color="ffffff", show_two_window=True,)
```

Int stands for integer, which is a type of programming variable that deals with numbers (hence why you might have the number 1280.0 in there, it's trying to find a number to work with). Here's a list of [reserved names](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/reserved.html) to help you avoid these errors again or to see if you named it something else you weren't supposed to.